# iOS UITableView Only Reloads Cell Data When Scrolling

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, xcode4

I am working on my first Objective-C app for iOS and am having an issue with reloading the data in a UITableView.

After reloading the data the cell content will only update when the cell is scrolled above of below the viewable area of the container.

Here is my .h code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AFHTTPClient.h"
#import "AFJSONRequestOperation.h"

@interface HelloWorldViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{
    NSMutableArray *tableViewArray;
    IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *tableViewArray;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *connectionLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textArea;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *userName;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *passWord;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSMutableString *serverResponse;
- (IBAction)callHome:(id)sender;
@end
```

and .m code:

```
#import "HelloWorldViewController.h"

@interface HelloWorldViewController ()

@end

@implementation HelloWorldViewController
@synthesize tableViewArray;
@synthesize connectionLabel;
@synthesize userName = _userName;
@synthesize passWord = _password;
@synthesize serverResponse = _serverResponse;
@synthesize tableView;
@synthesize textArea;
@synthesize textField2;
@synthesize label;
@synthesize textField;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    tableViewArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [tableViewArray addObject:@"TEST1"];
    [tableViewArray addObject:@"TEST2"];
    [tableViewArray addObject:@"TEST3"];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setTextField:nil];
    [self setLabel:nil];
    [self setTextField2:nil];
    [self setTextArea:nil];
    [self setTableView:nil];
    [self setConnectionLabel:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {
    if (theTextField == self.textField) {
        [theTextField resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [tableViewArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.tableViewArray objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];
    return cell;
}

- (IBAction)callHome:(id)sender {
    self.userName = self.textField.text;
    self.passWord = self.textField2.text;

    NSMutableString *tempResponse = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@""]; 

    AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/"]];

    [client  setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:self.userName password:self.passWord];

    [client getPath:@"login.do" parameters:nil 
            success:^( AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation , id responseObject ){
                NSLog(@"Authentication Success: %d", operation.response.statusCode); 
                self.serverResponse = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"Authentication Success: %d", operation.response.statusCode ]; 
                [tempResponse appendString: self.serverResponse];
                self.textArea.text = tempResponse;
            } 
            failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation , NSError *error){
                NSLog(@"Authentication Error: %@\n%@", error, operation);
            }
     ];

    [client getPath:@"test.json.do" parameters:nil 
            success:^( AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation , id responseObject ){
                NSLog(@"Retrieval Success: %d", operation.response.statusCode);
                NSDictionary *results = [operation.responseString JSONValue];
                NSMutableArray *buildings = [results objectForKey:@"buildings"]; 
                NSMutableArray *names = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
                for (NSDictionary *building in buildings)
                {
                    [names addObject:[building objectForKey:@"name"]];
                }
                self.tableViewArray = names;
                self.serverResponse = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"\nBuilding List Retrieval Success: %d", operation.response.statusCode ]; 
                [tempResponse appendString: self.serverResponse];
                self.connectionLabel.text = tempResponse;
            } 
            failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation , NSError *error){
                NSLog(@"Retrieval Error: %@\n%@", error, operation);
            }
     ];

    NSLog(@"tableView is: %@", [tableView description]);
    [tableView reloadData];
}

@end
```

When I call `[self.tableView description]`the result is null, but if I call it from `cellForRowAtIndexPath` then I get the following result:

```
tableView is: <UITableView: 0x8a71000; frame = (0 0; 280 191); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x6b7e860>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>. Delegate: HelloWorldViewController, DataSource: HelloWorldViewController
```

Here's a screenshot of interface builder:
[image]

All help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I added a screenshot of interface builder. I'm ctrl dragging from the highlighted table view to the Hello World View Controller. Thanks again...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably not connecting the UITableView in the interface builder..

You have to drag while pressing ctrl from the file's owner to the UITableView and connect it.

Also, you should not access your properties without self, you should do:

```
@synthesize tableViewArray = _tableViewArray;
```

and then access it with:

```
self.tableViewArray
```

try to avoid accessing your ivars directly, use the property!

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your response Heliem. I added a screenshot to the question. Maybe I'm dragging to the wrong place?

Comment: You have to drag the other way around, from the view controller to the highlighted table view

Comment: Ha! Xcode is too funny sometimes! That was it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have not hooked up your UITableView with the HelloWorldViewController tabelView property in IB.

Comment: Hello Peter, thanks for your help. I added a screenshot of my interface builder to the question. Please let me know if anything seems out of place.